# NSURLRequest returning nil

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsurlrequest

I am performing a simple download of data from a JSON service. When invoked the request returns a nil response object. This seems to be the same code I've used several times, but now I am stumped as to why the request returns nil. I have verified that the generated URL is valid and does return data. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

```
NSString *serviceEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?sites=%@&period=PT%luH&format=json", guageID, hours];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serviceEndpoint]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
// response is nil at this point
NSDictionary *rvData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonError];
```

Comment: try to encode your string using `[NSURL URLWithString:[serviceEndpoint stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]`.

Comment: Do not ignore the error parameter of the method: `sendSynchronousRequest`. Provide an `NSError` parameter and log it when the method returns nil.

Comment: Aargh! Synchronous URLRequests on the main thread blocks the UI! Have you no respect for your user's experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're totally disregarding the NSError and NSURLResponse that are also populated from the `sendSynchronousRequest` method.

First, add a check to inquire whether the NSError has been populated (if the NSURLResponse if nil), and if it is not nil, you should inspect it to determine the problem of the request.  You can also take a peak into the NSURLResponse object to also observe any properties to help debug the problem:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?sites=%@&period=PT%@luH&format=json", guageID, hours]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];
if (responseData != nil)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
}
else
{
   if (error != nil)
   {
       NSLog(@"Error description=%@", [err description]);
   }
}
```

Comment: One does _not_ check the `error` parameter for nil, one checks the `sendSynchronousRequest` method for nil and if nil examined the error parameter. an error out parameter is not guaranteed to be nil if there is no error.

Comment: The statement about the format statement wrt hours is most likely wrong, hours very well is a integer of some type (unsigned long perhaps) and the format specifier `%lu` would be correct. `%@` is only for objects.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Inspecting the error showed the real issue, that is the simulator in XC6 has a known issue of dropping its connection, even if connectivity is still available to the machine. As far as the %@ in the URL, it was actually %lu since the value passed in was NSUInteger

Comment: Ah ok, nice work.  I'll update my answer to remove that part about the NSString formatting.